# ImageLoader other than UIL

Tags: android, out-of-memory, universal-image-loader

It is really frustrating to use UIL libraray at github [link here](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

This work fine for all cases but don't stop to memory exceed.
I have read all the stackoverflow solutions. Implemented. but not succeeded.

Any one can help me to get out of this. OR suggest some new library.

Need to show images from url like facebook and dropbox and images from sdcard.

It show out of memory.

changes done: large heap true in manifest

Thanks

Comment: try picasso. http://square.github.io/picasso/

Answer (score 0):

you can try `AQuery` android library for lazy loading image and listview...below code may help you..... [download library from here](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/downloads/detail?name=android-query-full.0.25.10.jar)

```
AQuery aq = new AQuery(mContext);
aq.id(R.id.image1).image("http://data.whicdn.com/images/63995806/original.jpg");
```

Also Refer documentation [How to use AQuery in Android](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/#Image_Loading)

Comment: but i need to show images from gallery ie. sdcard images also.